# create multiple vectors for 2 for-loop in r

Tags: r

I have 3 variables:
First is time (`day`): `day <- seq(1,7,1)`
Second is level: `level <- seq(1,5,1)`
Third is product: `pro <- level*day + 1`
With each level, `day` from 1 to 7, I want to create a new vector pro, it means this new vector has 7 values.
Ex: `level = 1`, `day` from 1 to 7, `pro1 = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`
`level = 2`, `day` from 1 to 7, `pro2={3,5,7,9,11,13,15}`

```
sumpro <- function(day, level) {
  pro <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(level)){
    for (j in 1:length(day)){
      pro[j] <- level[i]*day[j] +1
    }
    return(pro)
  }
}

v <- sumpro(day, level)
v
```

Output:

```
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

This means that output prints the result of "pro vector" with level=1. How can I print the other "pro vector" at different levels?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `print` to print on screen while *in the loop*, but you should use `return` *at the end* of the function.

The returned value is just the value of the first call to `return`. Therefore, you shouldn't use `return` more than once in a function, which you do if you call it inside the loop.

I added some lines to have a matrix-like final output to be passed to  `return`.

Note the warning, are you sure it's doing what it should?

```r
day <- seq(1,7,1)
level <- seq(1,5,1)
pro <- level*day + 1
#> Warning in level * day: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object
#> length

sumpro <- function(day, level) {
  pro <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(level)){
    for (j in 1:length(day)){
      pro[j] <- level[i]*day[j] +1
    }
    print(pro)
    if (!exists("pros")) {
      pros <- t(pro)
    } else {
      pros <- rbind(pros, t(pro))
    }
  }
  return(pros)
}

v <- sumpro(day, level)
#> [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#> [1]  3  5  7  9 11 13 15
#> [1]  4  7 10 13 16 19 22
#> [1]  5  9 13 17 21 25 29
#> [1]  6 11 16 21 26 31 36
v
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#> [1,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
#> [2,]    3    5    7    9   11   13   15
#> [3,]    4    7   10   13   16   19   22
#> [4,]    5    9   13   17   21   25   29
#> [5,]    6   11   16   21   26   31   36
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Can you explain ```if (!exists("pros")) {
      pros <- t(pro)
    }``` What is "pros" (if a variable plus "s" means multiple?)? What is t(pro) function?

Comment: Hi! `pros` is created in your loop (first round, when it doesn't exist yet in your function), and assigned a value of `t(pro)`. The `t()` function transposes your `pro` vector (class numeric) to a single row (matrix and array class), such that the updated `pro` results can be binded using `rbind` in consecutive loop rounds. This gives the final returned matrix output. You can try the loop step by step (assign `i <- 1` and `j <- 1` and run the lines within the loop, after `for`) to see what happens in the firest round, then update i and j to see what happens in the next round.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is a case for `outer`.

sumpro <- function(day, level) outer(day, level, \(x, y) x*y + 1L)

sumpro(1:7, 1:5)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    2    3    4    5    6
#[2,]    3    5    7    9   11
#[3,]    4    7   10   13   16
#[4,]    5    9   13   17   21
#[5,]    6   11   16   21   26
#[6,]    7   13   19   25   31
#[7,]    8   15   22   29   36
```

Or pass one level at a time.

Comment: Can you explain ```\(x,y)```? Does it mean call day =x, level=y?

Comment: @Sam Yes, that's exactly what it means. For each value of `day`, call the function passing each value of `level`. The output is then a matrix of dimension `length(day)*length(level)`.